# Pointer to struct within the nested structs

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I'm trying to run the following code(in gcc 4.3 on fedora 11 i586 ):

```
#include <stdio.h>                       
#include <stdint.h>                      
#include <stdlib.h>                      

struct s_smallstruct{
  int smallstruct;
};                      

struct s_test2{
        char * test2;
        struct s_smallstruct* smallstruct;
};

struct s_test3{
        char * test3;
        struct s_smallstruct * smallstruct;
};

struct s_test1{
        char * test1;
        struct s_test2 * test2;
        struct s_test3 * test3;
};


int main(){
        struct s_test1 *test1 = (struct s_test1 *) malloc( sizeof test1 );
        test1->test2[0].smallstruct[0].smallstruct = 123;
        int num = test1->test2[0].smallstruct[0].smallstruct;
//      struct s_smallstruct * smallstruct = (struct s_smallstruct *) malloc( sizeof smallstruct );
//      smallstruct[0].smallstruct =12;
//      int num =  smallstruct[0].smallstruct;
        printf( "%d\n" , num );
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I got a segfault at test1->test2[0].smallstruct[0].smallstruct = 123; . Commented part is running without error. What is the reason of this behaviour. I'm not very proficient in C , so I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This is not a solution, but ALWAYS CHECK *ALLOC!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three problems with your code that I can see:

1. *sizeof* only tells you the size of the pointer, which is 4 for 32-bit pointers, not the size of the structure that is pointed to,
2. and even if you change sizeof to tell you the size of the structure, *malloc* will only allocate memory for the *s_test1* structure, not for the structures that are pointed to from within it,
3. and finally, the pointers in *test1*, *test2* etc. have to be initialized.

Here is something that works:

```
const int length = 2;    
struct s_test1 *test1 = malloc( length * sizeof *test1 );
test1->test2 = malloc( length * sizeof *test1->test2 );
test1->test2->smallstruct = malloc( length * sizeof *test1->test2->smallstruct );
test1[1].test2[0].smallstruct[1].smallstruct = 123;
int num = test1[1].test2[0].smallstruct[1].smallstruct;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
struct s_test1 *test1 = (struct s_test1 *) malloc( sizeof test1 );
```

to

```
struct s_test1 *test1 = (struct s_test1 *) malloc( sizeof struct s_test1 );
```

`test1` is a pointer, which in 32bit environments is 4 bytes.

Comment: Better is: malloc( sizeof *test1 );

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating any memory for the inner structs.  sizeof(test1) only has enough room for 3 pointers, not the entire struct of structs.

Plus, that statement has 5 (!) dereference operators in it.  Even if you had allocated a big enough chunk of memory, you haven't laid things out in a way that ensures it's contiguous -- you are asking it hop from block to block 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

I compiled the code marked as correct chosen by the question poster, @systemsfault , but got core dumped.  I hope to have a healthy and helpful discuss here to give the right solution for the question.  I am also pretty new to stackoverflow, so if I say anything wrong, please feel free to correct me.  Now, here we go...

Since the old solution didn't complile, there're 2 steps I tried to fix it.  First, I added for loops, but still got core dumped caused by (a1) and (a2).

Next, I used lines (b1) and (b2) to replace (a1) and (a2).  Now it compiled and runs correctly.

I have cleaned up the structs to make it simplier to read:

```
#include <stdio.h>                       
#include <stdlib.h>                      

struct s_smallstruct{
  int smallstruct;
};                      

struct s_test2{
  struct s_smallstruct *smallstruct;
};

struct s_test1{
  struct s_test2 *test2;
};

int main() {
  int i, j, length = 2;    

  struct s_test1 *test1 = malloc( length * sizeof *test1 );

  for (i=0; i<length; i++) {
    //test1[i].test2 = malloc( length * sizeof *test1->test2 );//(a1)
    test1[i].test2 = malloc( length * sizeof *test1[i].test2 );//(b1)

    for (j=0; j<length; j++) {
      //test1[i].test2[i].smallstruct = malloc( length * sizeof *test1->test2->smallstruct );//(a2)
      test1[i].test2[j].smallstruct = malloc( length * sizeof *test1[i].test2[j].smallstruct );//(b2)
    }
  }

  test1[1].test2[0].smallstruct[1].smallstruct = 123;
  int num = test1[1].test2[0].smallstruct[1].smallstruct;
  printf("num:%d\n", num);
  return 0;
}
```